# php - add two hours to date variable

Tags: php, date, addition, strtotime

I want to add 3 minutes to a date/time variable I have, but I'm not sure how to do this.
I made the variable from a string like this: *(which is in the RFC 2822 date format btw)*

```
$date = 2011-10-18T19:56:00+0200
```

I converted that string into date using this command:

```
$time = date_format(DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", $date), "G:i")
```

Now, I'd like to add 3 minutes to that variable, but I I'm not sure how.
I've used the following command in my script before, but that applies to the current date/time, so I'm not sure how to use that for my time variable:

```
$currenttime = date('G:i', strtotime('+2 hours'));
```

So, how can I add three minutes to the $time variable?

Answer (score 9):

```
echo $idate="2013-09-25 09:29:44";

$effectiveDate = strtotime("+40 minutes", strtotime($idate));

echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$effectiveDate);
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using the DateTime object already, stick with it:

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", $date);
$three_minutes = $time->add(new DateInterval('P2H'));
                                               ^^--two (2) hours (H)
```

Comment: An even better solution, as I do not want the current time to be modified, thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunatly, I don't get it to work... :S 
Ive got it like this now,:

`echo 'Arrival: '.date_format($time, 'G:i').'<br \>'."\n";`
`echo 'Departure: ';`
`echo ( $time->add(new DateInterval('P2H')) );`
`echo '<br \><br \>'."\n";`

but the page stops at the Departure echo...

Comment: the string format is incorrect. You need use $time->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));

Answer (score 4):

Use the second parameter of [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to provide a reference time:

```
$date_rfc2822 = '2011-10-18T19:56:00+0200';
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", $date_rfc2822);
echo date('G:i', strtotime('+2 hours', $dateTime->getTimestamp()));
```

Comment: This doesnt do what I want, I just figured out, as it takes the current time and adds 3 minutes, it doesnt get its time from the $datetime variable... am i correct?

Comment: @laarks No, the current time isn't used anywhere. Note that this exact demo program (when prefixed with `<?php`) always outputs `21:56`, no matter what time it is.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you're right then. But I already got another fix: i used strtotime twice :) which gets the date just fine aswell [from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812112/php-add-3-minutes-to-date-variable]

Answer (score 1):

> The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

That being said my solution to a similar problem is this:

```
// pretend that $date is what you got from mysql
// which is like 2013-02-12 23:08:17
echo "<br>";
echo $date;
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
echo "<br>";
echo $time->format('H-i-s');
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));
echo "<br>";
echo $time->format('H-i-s');
// Outputs:
// 2013-02-12 23:08:17
// 23-08-17
// 01-08-17
```

The thing is to add `P` when using `DateInterval` class, and `T` before time entries. For your case you need to go with `PT3M` for 3 minute addition. I was trying to add 2 hours and what I did was `$time->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));`.

If you would look at the interval specs:

```
Y   years
M   months
D   days
W   weeks. These get converted into days, so can not be combined with D.
H   hours
M   minutes
S   seconds
```

`M` for `months` and `M` for `minutes`. That is why there is a `T` in front of time.

At least that's what I want to believe... 'O_O

Answer (score 1):

```
//set the date and time

$start = '2017-01-01 14:00:00';

//display the converted time you want to add for ex. 1 hour and 20 minutes 

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1 hour +20 minutes',strtotime($start)));
```