# php - add 3 minutes to date variable

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime

I want to add 3 minutes to a date/time variable I have, but I'm not sure how to do this. I made the variable from a string like this: (which is in the RFC 2822 date format btw)

```
$date = 2011-10-18T19:56:00+0200
```

I converted that string into date using this command:

```
$time = date_format(DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", $date), "G:i")
```

Now, I'd like to add 3 minutes to that variable, but I I'm not sure how. I've used the following command in my script before, but that applies to the current date/time, so I'm not sure how to use that for my time variable:

```
$currenttime = date('G:i', strtotime('+2 hours'));
```

So, how can I add three minutes to the $time variable?

I tried this before:

```
$date = '2011-10-18T19:56:00+0200';
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", $date);
echo date('G:i', strtotime('+3 minutes', $time->getTimestamp()));
```

but that gives the current time with 3 minutes added, it doesnt use the $date variable...

And I tried:

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", $date);
$time = $time->add(new DateInterval('P2H'));
```

But then when I do

```
echo date_format($time, 'G:i');
```

nothing is echoed...

Any help here?

Comment: I thought I just saw this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - add two hours to date variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811609/php-add-two-hours-to-date-variable)

Comment: yeah kinda, though noone there responded, so I made a new question explaining what I already did, and as you see, I got much better results!
Damn i love stackoverflow! [and im only using it for about 3 days :P]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use `strtotime` twice:

```
$date = strtotime('2011-10-18T19:56:00+0200');
echo date('G:i', strtotime('+3 minutes', $date));
```

Comment: I don't see how that could work? how does it know how to decode $date?

Comment: `strtotime` is very powerful, from the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): "Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp". This means it will parse date strings like the one in your example, as well as providing the ability to add/subtract time. I've just tried the example and it works well :-)

Comment: Wow. That saves me a lot of extra long and complicated code I guess :P Thanks!
I'm going to try it now!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", $date);
$time = $time->add(new DateInterval('P2H'));
```

try (for adding 3 minutes)

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO", $date);
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT3M'));
```

First, since you're using PHP's DateTime class, you don't need to assign the output of the `add` method to a variable - it will modify the DateTime you passed into the constructor.  Second, if you're making modifications to time using the same class, you have to make sure there's a `T` before your time definition.  For your example, `DateInterval('P2H')` is invalid - it should be `DateInterval('PT2H')`.