# PHP Adding minutes to Time value

Tags: php, date, time, addition, strtotime

How can I add time to a digit time value,

currently my code looks like this:

```
$time = strtotime('00:00:00');

$addTime = strtotime('+5 minutes', $time);
$addTime = date('h:i:s', $addTime);
```

If I echo `$addTime` I get this value:

```
1472680800147268110012:05:00
```

which is obviously wrong.

It should look like this:

```
00:05:00
```

Comment: Here you go https://eval.in/632975

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - add two hours to date variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811609/php-add-two-hours-to-date-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$addTime = date('h:i:s', $addTime);` with `$addTime = date('H:i:s', $addTime);`

According to manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

**H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23**

Comment: wow.. I think this did it, I will test it a couple times more and if it still works I will give you a tick

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<?php
$addMinutes = 16;
$yourTime = new DateTime('08:02:00');
$yourTime->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $addMinutes . 'M'));

$result = $yourTime->format('H:i:s');

var_dump($result);
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/632952)

Comment: the thing is that it is not really a date just a digit time value

Answer (score 0):

Why don't simply write:

```
$time = strtotime('00:00:00');

$addTime = date('H:i:s', $time+5*60);
```

Comment: @SyedNoman I've edited using 'H:i:s' instead of 'h:i:s'. Thanks.